# MongooseJS: Hide Specific Documents From Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a User schema with a activated field of Boolean type. I want queries to only return documents which have `activated: true`. And I hope there is a more efficient and DRY way of doing so than adding a conditional to every find, findOne, or findById.

What would be the most effective approach?

Comment: the dry way seem to be the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while there may be some way to do this, it is generally a bad idea to always hide this information.

speaking from experience trying to do this with other languages and database systems, you will, at some point, want / need to load items that are not actived. but if you always and only return activated items, you'll never be able to get the list you need.

for your purposes, i would recommend creating a `findActive` method on your schema:

```
someSchema.static("findActive", function(query, cb){
  // check if there is a query and callback
  if (!cb){
    cb = query;
    query = {};
  }

  // set up an empty query, if there isn't one provided
  if (!query) { query = {}; }

  // make sure you only load activated items
  query.activated = true;

  // run the query
  this.find(query, cb);
});
```

with this method, you will have a `findActive` method the same as `findOne`, but it will always filter for activated items.

`MyModel.findActive(function(err, modelList){ ... });`

and it optionally supports additional query filters

`MyModel.findActive({some: "stuff"}, function(err, modelList){ ... });`

Comment: " speaking from experience trying to do this with other languages and database systems, you will, at some point, want / need to load items that are not actived."

That's a very good argument to convince me to use your approach. Plus by adding a boolean as second argument, I can tell the function to findOne or find all documents matching the query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at Mongoose `Query middleware` [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

> Query middleware is supported for the following Model and Query
>   functions.
>
> - count
> - find
> - findOne
> - ...

For example:

```
User.pre('find', function() {
  console.log(this instanceof mongoose.Query); // true
  this.activated = true;
});
```

Comment: isn't it same as db.user.find({activated:true}) , which he wants to avoid?

Comment: @AJS the goal is to not add this to every request, but add it somewhere on top (to be used automatically then).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I thought about the pre hook for queries. But I would have to write one for every of query helper function, no?